# Why value of a string variable is passed null in a post method of web api C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

Below is my post web api method.

```
public void Post([FromBody]string name)
{

}
```

When I try to send a request to this method from Postman, the value of the string variable name is always null. Below is the screenshot of Postman.

[image]

Comment: Try to use object instead of string because you're sending it as an object

Comment: @H.Pauwelyn thanks it worked, is there any specific reason why string was not working?

Comment: you send it as an object not a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is you send the object with the string as a field, not the string itself.
Here you need to send just a value to your post method (without brackets and field name).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could also change the object type inside your code

```cs
public string Post([FromBody]PostObject postObj)
{
    return $"Hello, {postObj.Name}!";
}

public class PostObject 
{
    [JsonProperty("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

In that way you could send a lot more then only a string and your Postman call wouldn't change.